# JAVA without IDE JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I have this java project and I'm not using an IDE.

What do I need to do to have JSONObject available in my program?

What do I need to import?

My goal is parse a JSON response.

**edit**
I know what libs I need, I just dont know where to place their files or how to call them correctly.

Comment: Do you not know how to import or do you not know what is the fully qualified name of `JSONObject`? The former is quite fundamental, the latter can be found quite easily in the documentation.

Comment: I do not know how to import packaged without using an IDE. No idea where to place the files or call them. I just downloaded this and placed it in the my src folder https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java

Comment: I have this so far.... http://pastebin.com/8z9Ce1uy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on *which* JSONObject you need.

[The one from json.org](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) is packaged under `org.json`. Add this at the beginning of your files:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

and place `JSONObject.java` (if you have the file) in `your_project_dir/org/json/`. If you have a `jar` file, then the directory structure is already correct within the file and you only need to point the compiler to the `jar`.

Do you want the one from GWT? Try:

```
import com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject;
```

Then, if you have the source code, it belongs to the `com/google/gwt/json/client` directory.

Then there is a [jsonLib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html):

```
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
```

...

Comment: @baconator or your question is about the usage of the command line compiler (not how to write the source code)?

Comment: yea I guess. I already have the files from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java in the same directory were my java src is. I added the import for org.json.JSONObject but it cant find it.

Comment: @Baconator507 is the source code placed in the `json` subdirectory of the `org` directory in the project directory? That's where they should be based on their package.

Comment: No, there is only one directory and it contains the .java file im trying to compile and I dumped all the files from JSON.org in there too.

Comment: @Baconator507 then it's somewhere the compiler will never look for it.

Comment: Yes, I know that. My question is where do I place them? Lets say the src is at /src. Should I put the JSON.org files in /src/org/json ?

Comment: thanks man! Could you edit the answer and just put that last part about the path to place the files in?

Comment: @Baconator507 I already did.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://www.json.org/java/

How you use it  depends a bit on your build system. Are you sing Ant? Maven? If you have the jar on your build path you need to use "import org.json.*"

Comment: Yes, just that I dont know how to use it/import it